# can haar classifier be used for detection in a certain ROI instead of whole image?

Tags: c++, c

i want to apply viola jones on video for detection of faces in a certain ROI set by a tracker using camshift.

Comment: how is this related to c++ or c? if you are using some specific library mention that. C++ or C doesn't have any concepts you mentioned in the question.

Comment: i am using opencv library with microsoft visual studio.

Comment: The question is on-topic ([this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707620/viola-jones-face-detection-claims-180k-features) was too), but it is very poorly phrased.

Answer (score 0):

```
CascadeClassifier haarCascade;

Mat frame;
Rect roi;

Mat roiImg(frame, roi);

vector<Rect> objects;
haarCascade.detectMultiScale(roiImg, objects);
```