# learning phase of Viola Jones / AdaBoost

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, machine-learning, face-detection, adaboost

I have a Problem understanding the trainingsphase of the [Viola Jones algorithm](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/EE148-2005-Spring/pprs/viola04ijcv.pdf).

I give the algorithm in pseudo code, as far as I understand it:

```
# learning phase of Viola Jones
foreach feature # these are the pattern, see figure 1, page 139
    # these features are moved over the entire 24x24 sample pictures
    foreach (x,y) so that the feature still matches the 24x24 sample picture
        # the features are scaled over the window from [(x,y) - (24,24)]
        foreach scaling of the feature
            # calc the best threshold for a single, scaled feature
            # for this, the feature is put over each sample image (all 24x24 in the paper)
            foreach positive_image
                thresh_pos[this positive image] := HaarFeatureCalc(position of the window, scaling, feature)
            foreach negative_image
                thresh_neg[this negative image] := HaarFeatureCalc(position of the window, scaling, feature)
            #### what's next?
            #### how do I use the thresholds (pos / neg)?
```

This is, btw the frame as in this SO Question: [Viola-Jones' face detection claims 180k features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707620/viola-jones-face-detection-claims-180k-features)

This algorithm calls the HaarFeatureCalc-function, which I think I understood:

```
function: HaarFeatureCalc
    threshold := (sum of the pixel in the sample picture that are white in the feature pattern) -
        (sum of the pixel in the sample picture that are grey in the feature pattern)
    # this is calculated with the integral image, described in 2.1 of the paper
    return the threshold
```

any mistakes till now?

The learning phase of Viola Jones, basically detects which of the features/detectors are the most deciding. I don't understand how the AdaBoost works, that is described in the paper.

**Question: how would the AdaBoost from the paper look like in pseudo code?**

Comment: ask ml related questions in metaoptimize.. For this question is suited more there :)

Comment: I did, http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/9931/learning-phase-of-viola-jones-adaboost

Answer (score 0):

Viola Jones :

- First you will hard code 180k classifiers(feartures)
- And initially all the training data will have same weights
- Now each classifier(feature) will be applied to every training data you have
- Each feature will classify your training data as either a face or not a face
- based on this classifications for every feature you will calculate the error
- After calculating the error of each feature, you pick the feature with error that is most far away from 50% by which i mean if you have one feature with 90% error and other feature with 20% error then you will select the feature with 90% error and add it to the strong classififer
- You will update weights of each training data
- Now you will repeat the process untill you get a nice accuracy for you validation data with the strong classifier that you have built
- AdaBoost is a technique of making a strong classifiers out of weak classifier